# Merge NaN rows in pandas without losing cell values

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have dataframe similar to this

```
status  time  text
  1     12:25 some text
  NaN   NaN   status 1 txt
  NaN   NaN   s1
  2     15:23 some text
  NaN   NaN   status 2 txt
  NaN   NaN   s2
```

and i want to merge rows by status but i don't want to lose text cells, something like this.

```
status  time  text
1       12:25 some text status 1 txt s1
2       15:23 some text status 2 txt s2
```

I already tried grouping by status like this, but im losing the text cells.

```
df = df.groupby("status")[["time", "text"]].first().reset_index()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```py
df["grp"]=(~df.status.isna()|~df.time.isna()).cumsum()
df=df.groupby("grp").agg({"status": "first", "time": "first", "text": " ".join})
#optionally:
#df=df.groupby("grp").agg({"status": "first", "time": "first", "text": " ".join}).reset_index(drop=True)
```

Outputs:

```py
     status   time                       text
grp
1       1.0  12:25  some text status 1 txt s1
2       2.0  15:23  some text status 2 txt s2
```

Comment: I'm getting an exception "TypeError: sequence item 5: expected str instance, float found"

Comment: Try: ```df["text"]=df["text"].astype(str)``` beforehand

Comment: This worked! Never seen "~df.status.isna()" syntax, what tilda does?

Comment: ```~``` is negation - so it checks whether field is not na. Glad it worked:)